# While using as.POSIXct in a forloop in R I get this msg: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) character string is not in a

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

```
head(cab_train)
  fare_amount         pickup_datetime pickup_longitude pickup_latitude
1         4.5 2009-06-15 17:26:21 UTC        -73.84431        40.72132
2        16.9 2010-01-05 16:52:16 UTC        -74.01605        40.71130
3         5.7 2011-08-18 00:35:00 UTC        -73.98274        40.76127
4         7.7 2012-04-21 04:30:42 UTC        -73.98713        40.73314
5         5.3 2010-03-09 07:51:00 UTC        -73.96810        40.76801
6        12.1 2011-01-06 09:50:45 UTC        -74.00096        40.73163
  dropoff_longitude dropoff_latitude passenger_count Year
1         -73.84161         40.71228               1 2009
2         -73.97927         40.78200               1 2010
3         -73.99124         40.75056               2 2011
4         -73.99157         40.75809               1 2012
5         -73.95665         40.78376               1 2010
6         -73.97289         40.75823               1 2011

cab_train = cbind(cab_train, Year=" ")
str(cab_train)

cab_train$Year = as.numeric(cab_train$Year)
str(cab_train)

for(i in 1:nrow(cab_train))
{
  temp1 = 0
  temp1 = as.POSIXct(as.character(cab_train$pickup_datetime[i]))
  cab_train$Year[i] = format(temp1, "%Y")
}
str(cab_train)
```

Comment: We could try `as.POSIXct(as.character(cab_train$pickup_datetime[i]), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")`

Comment: Do you have `NA`s in `cab_train$pickup_datetime`? Why are you converting to character then POSIXct then extracting the year? What's wrong with `cab_train$Year <- as.numeric(substr(cab_train$pickup_datetime, 1, 4))`? You don't even need to do this in a loop - these functions all work on vectors.

Comment: Also, what Allan Cameron said above! And it would probably be better to put the *full* error message in the body of the question and use a shorter but concise title ;)

Comment: The full error message is : Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron , this worked